# SSIS: Import data from excel files, which are located in server, xlsx path link is available in database

Tags: sql-server, excel, import, ssis

I have created SSIS package, which imports data from xlsx files into sql server database and it is working fine. Currently I have set excel source this way, it takes xlsx files from defined location. 
But now I need to adjust it to take files from server, xlsx path links are defined in database.

Most probably I have to add task before excel source, which provides path link for source task. 
I hope that someone could give some step by step instructions.

Comment: Start here - it shows something similiar to what you want. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to follow below steps for your answer.
**Step 1**: Declare variables
1a. ExcelFilePath string variable whose scope is package.
1b. FilePathData as object variable
**Step 2**: Take Excute SQL Task
2a. Edit it - Pop up open
2b. Select or Create OLEDB connection
2c. select query which will give result set from SQL Server. Use it in SQL Statement.
2d. Select Result Set as FullResultSet
2e. SqlSourceType as Direct Input
2f. Select Result from left pan
2g. Set 0 in Result Name column and select FilePathData in Variable Name column
**Step 3**: Add ForEach Loop container and connect the Execute SQL task to it. Open the editor and click Collection. In the enumerator drop down menu, select ForEach ADO Enumerator. In the ADO Object Source Variable drop down menu, select FilePathData and for the Enumeration Mode, select Rows in the first table.
**Step 4**: Open Variable Mappings. In the drop down menu for the first variable, select ExcelFilePath. Click OK to close the editor.
**Step 5**: This ExcelFilePath variable use in your excel connection manager  to set expression ExcelFilePath in property.
**Step 6**: Other things you have already done in Data Flow Task

Comment: Thank you for step by step instructions, I followed your suggestions as directly I could, but no luck so far. Currently I got the following error:
"Foreach Loop Container 1: Variable "User::FilePathData" does not contain a valid data object"
Do you have any ideas, what to check? Instead of Execute SQL Task I used Execute T-SQL Statement task, which basically should be the same. Used it because seems that in visual studio version I use, there is no such task unfortunately. In database excel link path in database is define as hyperlink (examle: https://server/file.xlsx) - can it cause problem?

Comment: Please let me know your SQL Server Data Tool Visual Studio version and SQL Server version. Check this [Execute SQL task vs Execute T-SQL Statement task] (https://sunilreddyenugala.wordpress.com/2012/05/30/difference-between-execute-t-sql-statement-task-and-execute-sql-task/) So, you cannot assign result data to any variable using this task.

Comment: It was my bad, actually I have also "Execute SQL Task", I don't know how I didn't see it before. But I now tried with this task, but still no luck, error seems to be related to file creation:

"Error: 0xC0202009 at Package, Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager": SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Failure creating file."."

Can it be related to xlsx file location, it is defined as hyperlink: (https:/server../xlsx)

Comment: Yes, it seems to be related to the excel path link, which is in database. I created new excel connection manager and set ExcelFilePath as this hyperlink (https//server../file.xlsx) and it gave me same error. If I put this link directly into browser I am able to dowload the file. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: To download excel file from server to your local machine, you need to use script task under foreach loop container and after that you need to execute your data flow task. So, flow like 1 > Execute SQL Task 2. Foreach Loop Container 3. Script Task for download excel file [Example](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/downloading-multiple-files-from-internet-with-ssis-and-c) 4. Data Flow Task.

Comment: Not very familiar with C#, but I tried to follow the instructions. I would like to get this script task working separately first. So I created variable and added url into variable value.
Then I add this inside try:
string myURI = Dts.Variables["User::test"].Value.ToString(), myWebString = null, myLocalPath = null;
                myWebString = myURI;
                myLocalPath = "c:\\sql\\";
                WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
                myWebClient.DownloadFile(myWebString, myLocalPath);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to copy paste full code into comments. But other part is like same as in the example. Also If I execute the task, it will not show any error message just red X.